# How to assign a value to a selection menu (enquiries) on python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, terminal

Code:

```
options = ['1. Tell my name', '2. Tell my age', '3. Tell something funny']
choice = enquiries.choose('Choose one of these options: ', options)

if options == '1. Tell my name'
    name == input()
    print(name)
elif options == '2. Tell my age'
    age == input()
    print(age)
elif
    options == '3. Tell me something'
    story == input()
    print('Story saved')
else
    pass
```

Terminal:

```
  Choose one of these options: 
> 1. Tell my name
  2. Tell my age
  3. Tell something funny
```

How can I add a value to each of the options?

Like, for example, selecting the first option (Tell my name) the expected output would be:
`print(first option)`
Tried `if` but doesn't seems to work.

I added `pass` because the menu is interactive and you use the arrows instead of typing an option.

Comment: If it's ok, can you please provide your expected output? Thank you

Comment: Need more info on expected output

Answer (score 0):

The `choose` function returns the selected option so in your case you should check the returned choice rather than the options list. i.e.

```
options = ['1. Tell my name', '2. Tell my age', '3. Tell something funny']
choice = enquiries.choose('Choose one of these options: ', options)

if choice == '1. Tell my name': # <--- Note choice here instead of options
    name == input()
    print(name)
elif choice == '2. Tell my age': # <--- And here
    ... # etc
```